# Local notification show uialertview while app in background

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, uilocalnotification

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
```

The specific function is called when the app is in foreground. How can i show a local notification when the app is in background? I press the home button and then i want to show an uialertview to the user...is this possible?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if app isn't running in the foreground..then the notification is shown as a ALert View by default..

Comment: But the function is called only when the app is in foreground! I do not get it!

Comment: Oh ok i got it i was wrong it is called on background as well. Thanks.

Comment: when app is in foreground : its alertview by default. but when the app is in background it is similar with push messages.....got it?????